# laravel nested hasmany with where clause on last child

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get data from nested relationships with where clause on the last child, (as json nested response). I'm making an API with 4 nested models with hasmany relations like this:
modelA ->hasmany modelB ->hasmany modelC ->hasmany modelD
(modelA is first parent etc..)

I have a route on api.php

```
Route::get('/rdata/{string}', [ModelAController::class, 'getdata']);
```

On my ModelAController:

```
public function getdata($string)
{
    return ModelA::thedata($string);
}
```

And then on my ModelA

```
public static function thedata($string)
{ 
    return ...
}
```

I want to get data based on a field of the 4th ModelD. How can I do a where clause on the 4th child maybe something like this:

```
where('column', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')
```

I also tried with collection resources, I can get all the data nested fine but I cant perform the query I want on the last child. Best thing I've achieved is doing the query on the last child load parents but it doesnt work properly

```
return ModelD::where('column', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')->with('modelc.modelb.modela')->get();
```

or even with load

```
return ModelD::where('column', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')->get()->load('modelc.modelb.modela');
```

then on ModelC:

```
public function modelb()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ModelB::class, 'f_key','f_key');
}
```

and the same for the other parents but this is wrong as I get all the children inside them again and also the json is inversed. I want to keep the format:

```
 $response = ['ModelA' => [
                            'id' => '..'
                            'field1' => '..'
                            'ModelB'=>[
                                etc..
                            ]]
```

Or is there another way to do it that I don't see? In a way I need something like this but formated in nested json

```
return DB::table('modela')
->join('modelb', 'modela.id', 'modelb.modela_id')
->join('modelc', 'modelb.id', 'modelc.modelb_id')
->join('modeld', 'modelc.id', 'modeld.modeld_id')
->where('column', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')
->get();
```

Edit1: I got this so far based on the answer and I want to get parent columns on last child

```
return self::with('modelb.modelc.modeld')-> whereHas('modelb.modelc.modeld', function ($modeld) use ($string) {
    $modeld->where('column', 'like', "%$string%");
    ->whereColumn('modelc.column2', 'modeld.column2')
    ->whereColumn('modelc.column3', 'modeld.column3');
})
->with(['modelb.modelc.modeld' => function ($modeld) use ($string) {
    $modeld->where('column', 'like', "%$string%");
    ->whereColumn('modelc.column2', 'modeld.column2')
    ->whereColumn('modelc.column3', 'modeld.column3');
}])
->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that with `whereHas`/`with` Closures.

```php
ModelA::query()
    ->whereHas('modelb.modelc.modeld', function ($modeld) use ($string) {
        $modeld->where('column', 'like', "%$string%");
    ->with(['modelb.modelc.modeld' => function ($modeld) use ($string) {
        $modeld->where('column', 'like', "%$string%");
    }])
    ->get();
```

Something like this, but probably more refined in the conditions.

---

I think based on your edit, that this query should work for your needs.

```php
ModelA::query()
    ->whereHas('modelb.modelc', function ($modelC) use ($string) {
        $modelC->whereHas('modeld', function ($modelD) use ($string) {
            $modelD->whereColumn('table_c.column2', 'table_d.column2')
                   ->whereColumn('table_c.column3', 'table_d.column3')
                   ->where('table_d.column', 'like', "%$string%");
        });
    ->with(['modelb.modelc' => function ($modelC) use ($string) {
        $modelC->with(['modeld' => function ($modelD) use ($string) {
            $modelD->whereColumn('table_c.column2', 'table_d.column2')
                   ->whereColumn('table_c.column3', 'table_d.column3')
                   ->where('table_d.column', 'like', "%$string%");
        }]);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: this seems to be helpful but how can I use wherecolumn inside the queries on columns from modelC and modelD? ->whereColumn('modelC.column', 'modelD.column')

Comment: Can you post the whole query you're attempting to make? whereHas should take care of the joining conditions on its own but if your query has some other things, I could edit my answer

Comment: I want to get results if the string is equal to column on modeld but also where column2 and column3 are equal to parent modelc. I will edit question with code

Comment: I tried something similar and your answer and in both cases I get 1054 column not found, on my models I return this->hasmany(Child::class, 'fkey','lkey'), am I missing something?

Comment: Are the columns you're trying to filter by present in the database tables or are they accessors (`getColumnAttribute` functions) ?

Comment: yes they are present, I thought there was some foreign key problem and tried to remake the table with primary key of modelC as fkey on modelD but still says not found

Comment: is there another way to remove siblings an parents with no children from the returned response? Now I managed to get the wanted children with all data up to first parent but also get their empty siblings, any tips with laravel or just php?

Comment: Use both whereHas and with conditions for that.

Comment: I did but I think because I search from the top to bottom I also get empty siblings, I removed them with php loop but it will be nice to do it properly, I don't get why it says column not found, anyway thanks for your help, I will mark it as solved

Comment: You should leave it as unanswered if your problem is not solved.